# Which is correct "нахуй" or "на хуй"?

Tags: мат

I've seen many Russians write *"на хуй"* separately, or *"нахуй"* as one word, although I'm 99 % sure it should be written separately. Why is it so often written as one word? (Because the stress on на confuses them?) And is the spelling with a space the correct version?

Comment: First of all correct spelling are _на хуй_ and _нахуй_, there is no letter `*` is Russian alphabet. And yes, both spelling are correct since they stand for two different part of speech.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov I know * is not a letter, I just wanted to censor the word хуй. Nevertheless, when would you use the first one and when the latter?

Comment: Please delete the question, it reduces respect to the site because the sentences are used by very uncultured persons. The sentences should be used in the speech only, it's not important how to write it.

Comment: @sergzach This is also a part of a language. I don't like this discussion as well, but in other languages (English for example) these words are listed in the dictionaries and no one pretends that they do not exist.

Comment: @Artemix This is a part of the spoken language, not a part of the written one. It's a very harmful tendention to use spoken language as written one - often, without any sense. The language has it's emotional aspect and if emotions so 'homely' then they should be expressed in spoken method only.

Comment: @Artemix On the other hand it's important for history - to fixate a low level of national culture, so, may be the question is actual.

Comment: TT_ has given the correct answer, but there is also an issue of current Internet jargon, which often uses "нахуй" in order to go around clumsily written word censorship systems on some forums, chats, etc. As such it can be considered a neologism. However, it does beginning to look like it's here to stay.

Comment: I see your point, but come on - then something like "b4" should be added to Oxford dictionary...

Comment: Didn't they add dot-com?

Comment: @TT_ Also we are not talking about what should or shouldn't be added to any specific dictionary, but about a much broader concept of "language". I do not think that you would say that every word in any language can be added to any arbitrary book.

Comment: @sergzach it is very strange to delete purely linguistic question on the grounds you don't like some aspects of the language. Never do this again please. Once there was a wave of troll questions on SE, this is not one of them.

Comment: Существует наречие “нахуй”. Оно имеет смысл “зачем”. Также есть одноимённое междометие, которое используется просто в качестве связки слов в прдложении. Надень шапку, нахуй, а то простудишься.

 В отличение от наречия, “на хуй” надо понимать буквально. В любом случае, существует проверочное слово “в жопу”. Если сомневаетесь, как грамотно написать деловое письмо, замените “на хуй” на “в жопу”. Если смысл не изменился, то надо писать раздельно. А если “нахуй” можно безболезненно удалить их текста, то пишется слитно и выделяется, нахуй, запятыми.

Comment: These two expressions have different meanings, For example, Путин, иди на хуй! and Нахуй мне эта война,

Comment: @CocoPop: Нахуй это действительно наречие, но значение, скорее, незачем. But it really is different from "зачем" and from "незачем".

Comment: @markvs I didn’t write that myself – I copied it from a meme online 

Comment: @CocoPop: In the text you copied there is also the third meaning. "Нахуй" is used as a "conjunction". For example "Надень шапку, нахуй". Here "нахуй" can be (and usually is) replaced by other similar words, most common - блядь. That is, "Надень шапку, блядь" is used more often.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both spelling are correct since they stand for at least two different parts of speech.

As an adverb, *нахуй*  should be written as one word like any other adverb in Russian.

It can mean *totally, entirely*.

> Как ты заебала, заткни на́хуй свое ебало! (song by the band Evil Not Alone)

Or as a variant of *нахуя* meaning *why?*, *what for?*

> На́хуй вы вообще приперлись? (trivial phrase)
>
> Нахуя́ козе баян? (proverb)

A noun *хуй* preceded by the preposition *на* should invariably be written separately regardless of what sense it is used in.

In the literal sense (*хуй* = penis):

> Мой парень надел на хуй стаканчик и стал им болтать, чтобы получить звук трещетки... (random quote from google)

In the positive metaphorical sense:

> И рыбку съесть, и на́ хуй сесть. (proverb)

In negative metaphorical sense:

> Иди на́ хуй! (very common idiom)

Also it may be used as interjection:

> Я попью а, нахуй, всё, пиздец, не могу больше. (from the movie ‘Зеленый слоник’)

I tend to think it should be written as one word, but I can’t give any rationale now.

As for the causes for the solid misspelling, I don't think they have anything to do with the stress being on *на*. Stressed prepositions are still quite usual in Russian: *лечь на́ пол*, *зайти за́ угол*, *взять работу на́ дом*. It's most likely by analogy with directional adverbs such as *направо*, *налево*, *вперед*, etc. That would make a certain sense. However, *на хуй* in *иди на хуй* is considered as noun with preposition by the most competent people.

There's an empirical rule: if you can break a stable phrase up by sticking an adjective or some other form between its parts, then they're two separate words. You can definitely modify *хуй* with an adjective:

> Иди ты на большой и толстый хуй!

You can even omit it:

> Иди ты на большой и толстый! (really [in use](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%98%D0%B4%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B8+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%22))

Try to describe *право* or *лево* in *направо* / *налево* and you'll see the difference.

All of the above is also applicable to numerous euphemisms of *хуй*: на́ фиг / на́фиг (нафига́), на́ хрен / на́хрен (нахрена́), на́ хер / на́хер (нахера́).

Answer (score 5):

Следует улавливать тонкую грань в использовании вариантов «нахуй» и «на хуй». Существует наречие «нахуй». Оно имеет смысл «зачем»/«прочь». Также есть одноимённое междометие, которое используется просто в качестве связки слов в предложении.
Надень шапку, нахуй, а то простудишься
В отличие от наречия, «на хуй» надо понимать буквально. В любом случае, существует проверочное слово «в жопу». Если сомневаетесь, как грамотно написать деловое письмо, замените «на хуй» на «в жопу». Если смысл не изменился, то надо писать раздельно. А если «нахуй» можно безболезненно удалить из текста, то пишется слитно и выделяется, нахуй, запятыми.

http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9F%D0%9D%D0%A5

Comment: +1 for "проверочное слово «в жопу»" :)

Answer (score 4):

I decided to add my answer since I completely disagree with the accepted answer (Dmitry). The expression should be written separately — this is the grammatically correct form. If Dmitry could substantiate his answer, that would be interesting. The reference to the song can't be considered legitimate proof of the expression's correctness (and the song itself could be written incorrectly).
I believe нахуй written as a single word is meant to be part of the "olbanskii ezyg".

Comment: So you believe adverb in Russian may be written separately, don’t you?

Comment: @Dmitry Alexandrov  No, I believe this expression has only one correct form. Why do you think it's an adverb? For example, you can add Russian b-word after every word in any statement, does this make it an adverb? And what about "ebtvoyumat'" - I wrote it without spaces according to your logic.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov - Adverbs really _can_ be written separately in Russian: `под мышкой`, `на корточках`, `без удержу`, `в открытую`, etc. As for `нахуй` vs. `на хуй` there's an oppinion which is [a bit different from your view](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B9#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0) expressed in your answer.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov - I'd like to note that I don't stick to either oppinion, and I'm eager to find out truth, or call it the actual state of things as for those two alternative spellings.

Comment: @YellowSky I began to think I have not expressed myself clearly because I do not notice any essential differences between my answer and article you refer (except for I was not sure how an interjection _нахуй_ should be spelled, but anonymous Lurkmore author is quite sure that it’s solid word).

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov - Surely there're no essential differences between your answer and the article, only a minor one, the only difference the article states is that `нахуй` can also be an interjection.

Comment: @YellowSky An interesting thing about the link (thanks for pointing out!) is that it serves as justification for both Dmitry's and my opinions. The content of the link supports Dmitry, the style of the link rather has "olbanskie" roots. I do not see how "Существует наречие «нахуй»" is substantiated there.

Comment: @YellowSky Of course you are right about adverbial phrases spelled exactly as noun in some case with preposition. But I wonder is there sense to reckon _под мышкой_ among them. If you do that you have the only choice to consider _[нести] под мышкой_, _[нести] под мышками_, _[взять] под мышку_, _[взять] под мышки_, as four independent indeclinable (!) words. I found it quite ridiculous, did not you?  I know many dictionaries says so, so I am not asking references, I’m asking rationale.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov - _Слева_ and _налево_, _сверху_ and _вверх_ and many others also look like case forms, still those are indeclinable adverbs. You know it that lots of Russian adverbs are "frozen" noun phrases.

Comment: @YellowSky Should I also consider e. g. _на́ руки_ or _по́д ноги_ as indeclinable adverbial phrases?

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov - You know it already, _руки_ is a noun which can be used without prepositions, but _*корточки_ and _*мышки_ are not. My point is that `на́ руки` in `взял ребёнка на руки` is an adverb, because it often means that the kid is sitting on your legs (on your lap), and not on your arms, but in `он лил мне воду на руки` it is a noun phrase, a preposition + a noun.

As for 'хуй' it's more difficult to draw that borderline, but anyhow I really agree with you, and I did upvote your answer. I only wanted to draw your attention to those minor points you haven't covered.